# Thermistor to Celsius/Fahrenheit/Kelvin in MATLAB

Tags: conversion, temperature, matlab, voltage, pin

## Thermistor to a Temperature Unit in MATLAB

I am using an `Analog Read Pin` on an *Arduino Uno* to read the temperature as given by a thermistor. The resistor being used on the thermistor is `220`. What I cannot manage to do is convert the voltage reading I get from the thermistor to Kelvin, Celsius, or Fahrenheit. Can anyone help me convert this reading to an actual temperature unit so I can actually use the values that I read.

---

Thanks for everyones help in advance!

---

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/5306OSKR-MXD-5501-040107_2.htm?&cc=US&lc=eng It seems to be exactly what you are doing

Comment: I am so insanely lost @EricF, is there one equation that I can use?

Comment: What type of thermocouple do you have?